# panic: open template/layout-main-page.html: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: html, go

I'm new in Golang and I'm trying to run a simple test in my application but a panic occurs everytime. I can't find what is the problem.

I've looked in several places but couldn't find a solution.

Feel free to ask me anything about the code, if you have any questions, just ask.

The error mensage:

```
PS D:\projetos go\api-ranking-crypto> go test ./test/
panic: open template/layout-main-page.html: The system cannot find the path specified.

goroutine 1 [running]:
html/template.Must(...)
        D:/Go/src/html/template/template.go:374
github.com/maickmachado/upvote-api/controllers.init()
        D:/projetos go/api-ranking-crypto/controllers/controllers.go:15 +0x1d8
FAIL    github.com/maickmachado/upvote-api/test 0.209s
FAIL
```

My test code:

```
    func TestHealthCheck(t *testing.T) {
    tt := []struct {
        name   string
        method string
        statusCode int
    }{
        {
            name:   "status ok",
            method: http.MethodGet,
            statusCode: http.StatusOK,
        },
    }
    for _, tc := range tt {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            request := httptest.NewRequest(tc.method, "/healthcheck", nil)
            responseRecorder := httptest.NewRecorder()

            controllers.HealthCheck(responseRecorder, request)

            if responseRecorder.Code != tc.statusCode {
                t.Errorf("Want status '%d', got '%d'", tc.statusCode, responseRecorder.Code)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The controller file:

```
var (
    TmplMainPage   = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template/layout-main-page.html"))
    TmplDetailPage = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template/layout-detail-page.html"))
    TmplError      = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template/layout-erro.html"))
    TmplRanking    = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template/layout-ranking.html"))
)

func GetAllData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {...}

func GetRanking(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {...}

func CryptoDetail(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {...}

func VoteCrypto(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {...}

func HealthCheck(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    io.WriteString(w, `{"alive": true}`)}
```

My main file:

```
func init() {
    database.CreateMongoBD()
}

func main() {
    routes.HandleRequest()
}
```

My route file:

```
func HandleRequest() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/cryptocoins", controllers.GetAllData).Methods("GET")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/ranking", controllers.GetRanking).Methods("GET")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/cryptocoins/{name}", controllers.CryptoDetail).Methods("GET")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/healthcheck", controllers.HealthCheck).Methods("GET")
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/cryptocoins/vote/{text}", controllers.VoteCrypto).Methods("POST")
    myRouter.NotFoundHandler = http.Handler(http.HandlerFunc(controllers.ErrorHandler404))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", myRouter))
}
```

Comment: please don't use screenshots for text.  Copy and paste the text itself.

Comment: changed, sorry.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I'm sorry, I couldn't follow you, how do I check this?

Comment: @CeriseLimón The path is correct(I think). The error occurs just when I run the test.

PS D:\projetos go\api-ranking-crypto> dir template/layout-main-page.html
Diretório: D:\projetos go\api-ranking-crypto\template

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-a----        05/10/2022     12:33            987 layout-main-page.html

Comment: The code specifies the template file using a path relative to the working directory (read about working directories [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)).  Either the working directory is not what the code expects or the file does not exist.  Specifying a template file by a relative path in the source code is fragile — the code's assumption about the working dir may not match the actual working dir. The preferred solution is to [parse the templates](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#ParseFS) from an  [embedded file system](https://pkg.go.dev/embed#hdr-File_Systems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cerise Limón and her answer in another post.

I changed some things.

Put the template inside the Handle function and take out the template.Must from it:

```
func ErrorHandler404(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    TmplError, _ := template.ParseFiles("./template/layout-erro.html")

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
    data := models.DetailPageData{
        PageTitle: "Erro 404 - Not Found",
    }
    err := TmplError.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```